# How to protect my live streaming from other websites on nginx

Tags: stream, locking, http-live-streaming, rtmp, live

I have big problem with my live stream i have on nginix
I want to lock my .m3u8 from any website and only work in my domain only because many websites steal my live stream and it make huge load on my vps
please help me my live stream stopped every time because hi load and other websites eat my bandwidth too

Thanks

Comment: You could use an `HTTP-Referer` header check, but that's not 100%

Comment: You could also encrypt the stream with AES HLS which is not as secure as a DRM but is free and may be enough to discourage people copying.